# call intercept in custom method in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, intercept

In the signInWithToken method, I get a token that needs to be set in the request header to 'Authorization', `Bearer ${token for here}`. But the problem is that when the signInWithToken method is called, a redirect occurs and the intercept () method does not have time to be called. How do I force the intercept () method to be called inside the signInWithToken () method? They are both inside the same service.

```js
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (this.access) {
      req = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.access}`)
      });
    }
    
    ...  // standard code for intercept
    
  }

  signInWithToken(login: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('./api/internal/auth/sign-in-with-token', {login, password}).pipe(
      map((details: SignInDetails) => {
        this.areCookiesValid = true;
        this.access = details.token; // in this method, when we received the token, we need to call intercept

        return details;
      }),
      catchError((error) => throwError(error))
    );
  }
```

Comment: `catchError((error) => throwError(error))` ... What are you trying to do here? That literally does nothing as far as I can tell?

Comment: @ Mrk Sef, yes, this line does not make any sense here, as well as `this.areCookiesValid = true;`, just forgot to delete. I just need to call the standard Angular method in another method

Comment: It looks like, in intercept, you're trying to run some synchronous code before you return an observable? When you mix synchronous and asynchronous code like this, sometimes it works, but you often get unexpected and had to debug errors. Also, intercept doesn't take a token as a paramter, what params are you sending it? (You can edit/update your question)

Comment: @Mrk Sef, I call intercept() with default parameters [req and next](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor), and pass the token through a variable inside the service. I just assumed that it is possible to somehow initiate an intercept () call indirectly, for example using [Location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)